# Cannot edit contacts in Marshmallow / Gmail contacts sync

Tags: contacts, gmail, nexus-4, 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5x

Merry Christmas!

So, I recently upgraded from Nexus 4 to 5x. My contacts used to live on the sim, but since having to change sim (micro -> nano). I exported the contacts using the Contacts app to a .vcf file. I have now imported these contacts to my Gmail account via web.

On my Nexus 5x (6.0.1 update), I cannot see how I can sync contacts from Gmail. I have an issue where I cannot edit **some** contacts if I just import straight from the vcf file. I am logged in to my Gmail account.

This should be a simple task and I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it. I was browsing the Apps list and I had Google Contacts Sync app disabled, thinking I wouldn't use it. The edit pencil icon is now visible.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your Google accounts from your phone, clear data for contacts and phone app. Delete your personal contact information (access it from notifications), then restart your phone and re-add your Google account.